Eclipse IDE search window unreadable when using Dark UI theme
In Eclipse IDE when using the Dark UI theme, the Search Results window highlights matching text with an unreadable light color on a light background.
There are other 'search' and Annotate color selections under Preferences
but none of these affect the search results window.
Q: Where in Eclipse > Preferences, or elsewhere in Eclipse, are the Search Results window colors controlled?
==========
What I expected and what I did to try resolving the issue:
I looked for 'Search' items and 'Color' items under Preferences but did find any items that affected the text colors in the Search Results window.
I would expect (a) the Dark theme not to make parts of the Eclipse UI unreadable by using incompatible foregound background colours. (b) that where colours are controlled that both the foreground and background colour to be seletable. (c) that there be a specific entry in Preferences for the Search Results window, just like there is a specific entry in Preferences to control the Build Console display colors. None of the above expectations are met in Eclipse.

This is not reproducible via Search > File... for me in the current Eclipse IDE 2024-06 with the built-in dark theme. Please make sure that your Eclipse IDE is up to date. If you can reproduce the problem in the current Eclipse version, please show a screenshot, tell us which operating system you are using and in which search it is exactly (Eclipse is an extensible platform with different kind of built-in searches and maybe searches from additional installed plugins, each of them displaying their own results).

Thanks for you response. My Eclipse is out of date because of the platform I am developing for.
O/S is Ubuntu 16.04.
Eclipse is:
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500
A link to the screenshot is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/nrlvsm36pwxpfyygcgddq/Eclipse-search-screenshot.png?rlkey=92ddgrqwncpl3i5xpog9uhf9v&st=m0115nl1&dl=0

Fixes for things like this are put in the current release. So this has probably been fixed in one of the 26 releases since Eclipse Neon

@gb-1957 Screenshots can and should be directly included in your question, so long as they aren't the sole source of information.
